# Signing into Bitbucket with Stack Exchange OpenID via delegate doesn't work

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

I go to `bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/`, enter my OpenID URL `omega.palle.net`, and get sent to openid.stackexchange.com. If I'm not logged in, I can enter username and password, and get asked for confirmation. Then I end up in one of two places:

- `openid.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/openid/provider`
- `openid.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/openid/resume`

Both contain the text:

> An error occurred on the server
>
> This event has been recorded.
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.

I am unsure how to provide more information. The history on my "profile" tells me that I have authenticated with bitbucket.org, I just don't get sent to the correct return path it seems?

Browsers I have tested are Firefox Nightly (30.0a1), Google Chrome 33.0.1750.146 and Safari 7.0.2

Comment: Can you repro this in Chrome/Safari/IE?

Comment: I don't have IE available, but it fails in the same way in Safari

Comment: Did it ever work before? I get the same error with ask.fedoraproject.org, [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225730/255589), but it used to work two months ago.

Comment: It has never worked for me with bitbucket, no. I switched to stackexchange OpenID after myopenid closed shop earlier this year.

Comment: @rene: Fails on Chrome here. Even without delegate

Comment: @erik: Yes, this used to work; it used to be my primary way of authenticating at bitbucket.