# Stack Exchange OpenID not working on ask.fedoraproject.org: An error occurred on the server

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-openid

I have used my Stack Exchange credentials many times via OpenID to login to ask.fedoraproject.org, but one or two months ago it stopped working.

Whenever I click on https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/account/signin/?next=/en/ and select OpenID and then enter http://stackexchange.com as OpenID URL I get, after entering my Stack Exchange email and password, this error page:

https://openid.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/openid/provider

With the following text:

```
An error occurred on the server

This event has been recorded.

If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.
```

Looks similar to this error which I found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222524/255589)

[image: openid error on the server]

I clicked on the highlighted *please report it* and reported it in hope of finding a solution.

Comment: Re-tagged as a bug as it could be related to ongoing work being done to overhaul the login system (may not be too, but this will get a dev to look at it sooner)